# Navigate first and then have viewDidLoad be called in an iphone app

Tags: iphone, pushviewcontroller, navigationcontroller

I am new iPhone developer. I have created an application in which I use `pushViewController` to navigate between views. But when I call :

```
DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
```

then the `viewDidLoad` method of DetailViewController is called.
And then I can navigate the screen.

But I want to navigate first and then the have the viewDidLoad method be called.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The nib/xib is loaded before the controller is pushed onto the navigation stack. Can't you move the viewDidLoad code to viewDidAppear or something like that?